# Bigquery: run a query multiple times based on different date_trunc and union the results, instead of multiple UNION ALLs

Tags: google-bigquery, recursive-query, union-all

I am looking to pull and union similar aggregations from a core table, but differing on the time period truncation. Eg this is how I would normally do so:

```
with base as (
  select 
    event_datetime
    , event_location
    , event_uuid
  from events_table
)

select
  date_trunc(event_datetime, day) as day
  , "day" as period_type
  , event_location
  , count(distinct event_uuid) as number_events
from base
group by day, event_location

union all

select
  date_trunc(event_datetime, week) as week
  , "week" as period_type
  , event_location
  , count(distinct event_uuid) as number_events
from base
group by week, event_location

union all

select
  date_trunc(event_datetime, week) as month
  , "month" as period_type
  , event_location
  , count(distinct event_uuid) as number_events
from base
group by month, event_location
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to avoid having to maintain three separate subqueries and have a single subquery that re-runs based on the different date_trunc and unions the results (producing the same output as code above)? I know someone at my previous company accomplished this, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  day, 
  period_type, 
  event_location, 
  count(distinct event_uuid) as number_events
from base t, 
unnest([
  struct('day' as period_type, date_trunc(event_datetime, day) as day),
  struct('week', date_trunc(event_datetime, week)),
  struct('month', date_trunc(event_datetime, month))
]) 
group by day, period_type, event_location
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail - thank you again for your answer above! I added a follow-up / alteration to the edit above. Would really appreciate if you could take another look and help me once again :)

Comment: This is not how it works here on SO. If you have new or follow up question - please post it as a new question and I/we will be happy to help. Meantime, please rollback your question to its original state

Comment: My apologies! That makes sense. I removed the edit above and made a new question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68538191/bigquery-run-a-query-multiple-times-based-on-different-when-statement-time-date

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Will check shortly

Comment: glad it worked for you - consider also voting up the answer! :o)